# A nodejs package contains CoffeeScript. What to do?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I npm installed the node-term-ui package, but I keep getting "Unexpected string" errors, then I noticed the syntax in the files looks different, and realized it's CoffeeScript which I've never used before.

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

zeMirco's answer is correct, but let me add more info: What `node-term-ui` is doing is very, very unusual. The author has set `main` in their `package.json` to point to a `.coffee` file, rather than compiling that file to a `.js` file. They also haven't noted this in their README. I see that there's now discussion about this at https://github.com/jocafa/node-term-ui/issues/2.

The need for a `.js` file may not have occurred to the author because, if you're running a `.coffee` file, you can `require`  other `.coffee` files. In fact, all you need to require `.coffee` files directly is to require the `coffee-script` module first. So what you could do in your JS file is:

```
require('coffee-script');
var TermUI = require('node-term-ui');
```

Be sure to add `coffee-script` as a project dependency first.

I hope the author will modify the library so that CoffeeScript isn't required to use it, but that workaround should be easier than zeMirco's solution of compiling the module manually.

Comment: Very informative. Thanks. Now that I know your answer, indeed I think that is the easiest thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

Just compile it into javascript

```
npm install -g coffee-script

coffee --compile TermUI.coffee // assuming you are inside the modules main folder
```

and then instead of requiring the module require the created `TermUI.js` file

```
var termui = require('./node_modules/node-term-ui/TermUI.js')
```